# What kind of ambiguity is this called?

Tags: ambiguity

> > "We've only got a thousand dollars, you know. Winning against him is impossible."

In this context, "winning against him is impossible" does not mean that it is impossible, in general, for anyone to beat him. Rather, it means that the speakers can't beat him at whatever situation they are in. However, words like "for us" and "here" to indicate this are omitted, and I can't come across a term to describe this. The closest I have come to is ellipsis, but none of the examples on wikipedia seem to fit what I'm looking for.

Comment: Well, in context it isn't ambiguous.

Comment: When you supply the missing subject for _win_ (_for_ Indef` vs _for us_) it becomes unambiguous. Deletions cause ambiguities.